# How to handle 0 Content length in POST request in CGI?

Tags: c++, linux, http, cgi

In my CGI application something happens when I pass a 0 content length POST request. Here is my code:

```
char* len_ = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
char* type_ = getenv("REQUEST_METHOD");
if(len_ != NULL)
{
    // The code crashes somewhere here
    long int len = strtol(len_, NULL, 10);
    char* postdata = (char*)malloc(len + 1);
    if (!postdata) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    //fgets(postdata, len + 1, stdin);
    string temp = "";
    fstream ff;
    string fileName = string(XML_DATA_DIRECTORY) + string("data.xml");
    ff.open(fileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::out | ios::trunc);
    // ff.open(fileName.c_str());

    if(ff)
    {
        // Modified: To handle new line in the Xml request
        while(fgets(postdata, len + 1, stdin) != NULL)
        {
            temp.append(postdata);
        }
        ff << temp;
    }
    else
    {
        // Error on the ifstream
    }
    ff.close();
    //free(postdata);
}
else
{
    // No Data
}
```

I test my application using the Http-Requester plugin for FireFox, when I pass a POST request with no data, the application seems like it enters a loop and no response. If I pass a GET request, the code works fine because `len_` becomes NULL and it exits the if statement. If I pass a POST request with data, it works fine and receives the data well and saves it.

The case I can't figure out is POST with CONTENT_LENGTH = 0. How to figure this case ? I tried `strlen(len_)` but it did not work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the content-length is zero, then there's simply nothing to read. So you can skip almost all of the code you have. It's the same case as if there is no content-size header field.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , I can't determine when the content length zero, because 'len_' does not return null when content length is zero. Somehow the program hangs or crashes in the if statement.
@ Deduplicator, Sorry for the typo!

Comment: No but even if it's non-null the length of the string will be zero ***or*** the variable `len` (after conversion) should be zero, shouldn't it?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Your point worked for me. After doing the log it appears that 'len' is equal to 0. I appreciate if you put it an answer. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @3bdalla: **This is not C**, so please do not insist on the wrong tag.

Comment: I'm not insisting on the wrong tag. The web page did not load correctly few hours ago. So I thought this is what you meant, sorry! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `getenv` returns `NULL`, e.g.:

```
char* len_;
long int len;

len_ = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
if (len_ && sscanf(len_, "%ld", &len) == 1) {
   if (len > 0) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Note that (as pointed out by @Deduplicator) is better to declare `len` as `unsigned long` or `size_t` because `CONTENT_LENGTH` (the number of bytes being sent by the client) is always positive.

Comment: Wouldn't `%lu` be better?

Comment: @Deduplicator, `len` is not `unsigned` ;)

Comment: Did not work. The program enters the if statement even with this new condition. Again I still send 0 data to get CONTENT_LENGTH to 0. I made a log file and before each line of the if statement I print to the log, the program hangs at this line 'while(fgets(postdata, len + 1, stdin) != NULL)', the log statements after this loop are not printed to the log file.

Comment: @AlterMann: This was a code snippet I found on the internet. Will it make difference ?

Comment: Use `malloc` only for allocating memory that is going to be managed by `c` libraries.